# Bind material datasource with the form

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I have a form. I need to bind it with a mat table datasource. That table should be editable. Thus I put input field inside mat row. How can I bind this array of data in the table with the form? This form can be a template driven or reactive forms. Appreciate your help

Comment: I would very much like to get an answer on this as well. in particular how to reference a row number in a mat-cell.